# If $A \subseteq B$, then prove by using laws of logic that $(A \times B) \cap (B \times A) = A^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I think I know the first step but I need some hints on how to complete it.

Let, $(x,y)$ is an element of $(A \times B) \cap (B \times A)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**. You have to show $(A\times B) \cap (B \times A) \subseteq A^2$ and $A^2 \subseteq (A \times B) \cap (B \times A)$. You started the first part.

(1) Let $(x,y) \in (A\times B) \cap (B \times A)$. Write down what in means for $(x,y)$ to be in this intersection. Recall what is means for $(x,y)$ to be in a cartesian product.

(2) For the other direction, start with: Let $(x,y) \in A^2$. That is $x \in A$ and $y \in A$. Now use that $A \subseteq B$. What can you say now about $(x,y)$ is it in $A\times B$? And in $B \times A$?

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y)\in A\times B$ means that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. And $(x,y)\in B\times A)$ means that $x\in B$ and $y\in A$.

So $(x, y) \in (A\times B)\cap(B\times A)$ means $x, y\in A$ and $x, y\in B$.

Now if $A \subset B$ we have that $x, y \in A$ implies that $x, y \in B$ and so implies $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\cap(B\times A)$

Comment: Just to show an alternative style, I would write down this proof as follows.$\newcommand{\XQ}[1]{\\\equiv\quad&\quad\unicode{x201c}\mbox{#1}\unicode{x201d}\\\quad&}$ It is clear that every element in each side is a pair. Therefore, it is sufficient to prove, for every$\;x,y\;$,$$\begin{align}\quad&(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap (B\times A)\XQ{definition of$\;\cap,\times\;$}x\in A\land y\in B\;\land\; x\in B\land y\in A\XQ{since$\;A\subseteq B\;$,$\;z\in A\;$ implies$\;z\in B\;$}x\in A\land y\in A\XQ{definition of$\;\times\;$}(x,y)\in A\times A
\end{align}$$